# Output Number, without digits after decimal place

Tags: java, android

**ANDROID STUDIO HELP, THE VB.NET CODE ARE EXAMPLES - (SOLVED !!)**

I'm coming from VB.NET (2+ Years).

Need help outputting Double variable, without digits after decimal place.

I understand that an integer is a number without any digits after the decimal place.

In Visual Basic or VB.NET, I can do this by doing this..

```
 Dim Variable_Name_A as Decimal = 12.0123990110001
 Variable_To_Hold_It = Decimal.Truncate(Variable_Name_A)

 Outputs : 12
```

Val treats a String or TextBox as a Double.

So how can we do this in Java or for Android Studio?

Also, if you can answer but just one more question. How do you get rid of the negative symbol in Android Studio.. In VB.NET I can type the following code, to get rid of it.

```
 Dim My_Variable_Name_A as Double = -12.00017
 My_Variable_Name_B = Math.Abs(My_Variable_Name_A)

 Outputs : 12.00017
```

So, I've taken a look at "Formater" for Android Studio. I've read countless posts that deals with digits after the decimal place. I don't understand any of it.

I DO NOT WANT ROUNDING.

In VB.NET, if I wanted to "Format" a number, we usually do something like this..

```
Dim Variable_Name_A as Double = 13.00192012334
Variable_Name_B = format(Variable_Name_A, "0.000")
Output : 13.002
```

I just need the whole number, before the decimal place for Android Studio, I don't want the numbers after the decimal place.

Also.. If you could.. WITHOUT ROUNDING.. Could you please tell me how to Format the number as well. Yes, with X number of digits after the decimal place.

Can you please help with my first question, and help me with the other questions if you can.

*** So I figured it out..  ***

```
EditText Millimeters_VARa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Millimeters_EditText_ID);
Double MM_Double = Double.parseDouble(Millimeters_VARa.getText().toString());

EditText Inches_VARa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Inches_EditText_ID);

DecimalFormat WholeNumber = new DecimalFormat("0");
DecimalFormat WholeAndThousandths = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

// Converts Millimeters to Inches.
Double MM_to_Inches_Convert = (MM_Double / 25.4);

Inches_VAR.setText(WholeNumber.format(MM_to_Inches_Convert));
Output Example : 2

Inches_VAR.setText(WholeAndThousandths.format(MM_to_Inches_Convert));
Output Example : 2.000
```

So, it seems it only works when finally outputting the value.

How would I store the formatted number or value in a Double Variable?

Ahh.. I figured it out. Like this?

*** Storing a Formatted Number or Value as a Double ***

```
Double TheWholeNumber = Double.parseDouble(WholeNumber.format(MM_to_Inches_Convert.toString()));
```

NOPE !! Doesn't work.. App Crashes.. Just keeping it simple, and formatting the number when finally outputting it with the `setText`.

But of course it rounds the last digit. So, now I'm gonna learn how to fix that.

**PREVENTING FROM ROUNDING - SOLVED**

```
public void FormatFunction(View v){
EditText EditText_VAR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText_A);
Double EditText_Double =     Double.parseDouble(EditText_VAR.getText().toString());
TextView TextView_VAR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_A);

DecimalFormat LOL = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
LOL.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

TextView_VAR.setText(LOL.format(EditText_Double));
```

**Voilà**

That's how ya do it. I also understand now what the difference between using a pound sign "#", vs. using just a zero. The pound sign prevents trailing zeros.

The Class Name, FormatFuncion is called by a button Click.

```
<TextView
android:textSize="22sp"
android:id="@+id/TextView_A"
android:text="@string/OUTPUT_STRING"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<EditText
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
android:id="@+id/EditText_A"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>

<Button
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/EditText_A"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:text="@string/Format_String_A"
android:onClick="FormatFunction"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can clearly see.

This post should help anyone looking for the Answer to formatting a number, as well as how to prevent rounding. SOLVED.

Android programming is a little difficult. It takes much longer then programming in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2010. Apps for Windows OS. I could, lol, Correction.. "I HAVE" made apps a couple times already in VB.NET, and it sure as hell beats the snot out of Programing for Android. As far as the amount of time it takes to make an App for my $700+ (Android) Samsung Galaxy Note 4. I just hate.. Sorta.. typing my layout. It's time consuming. Also, in order to get things to line up correctly, as in making a button under another button, or on the right, left, etc. If you have multiple other objects, gotta say stuff like `An Example : android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EditText_A"`

Just a pain in the A**, IMHO. But I love Coding for Android. Regardless if it takes some learning, and head scratching. Just much slower then VB.NET, by far.

Answer (score 1):

1)Convert Double to String.

2)perform String.Split

3)join the two split parts again to a string

4)Parse String to Long 
 
5)Wallah double without decimal

```
double dbNum=11112.1111;

    String []dbStore=Double.toString(dbNum).split(".");

    String strDBNum="";
    for(String str:dbStore)
    {
        strDBNum+=str;
    }

    Long lDbNum=Long.parseLong(strDBNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
double number = 1205.6358;
System.out.println("number : " + number);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###");
System.out.println("number (DecimalFormat) : " + df.format(number));
```

Comment: Ok.. Tried casting it to an Integer (int).

Did not work.

http://oi60.tinypic.com/30bpefp.jpg

Comment: You'll want to use `int TheWholeNumber = (int)Millimeters_Double;`

Comment: For the df, try `DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat("#");
  String result = df.format(Millimeters_Double);
  Inches_VAR.setText = result;`

Comment: Also figured out that it needs to be a Double. Can't just convert whatever is in EditText. Need to parse it. 
`TextView TVa = (TextView) findViewById(TextView1);`
`EditText EditTextA = (EditText) findViewById(EditText1);`
`Double ET_Dbl = Double.parseDouble(EditTextA.getText().toString());`

`DecimalFormat LOL = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");`

Preventing it from Rounding..
`LOL.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);`

**The Output**
`TVa.setText(LOL.format(ET_Dbl));`

Android Studio says there's no need to put the `.toString`, it's redundant.
So I just left it. My App doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Java has this nifty little feature called a cast. Cast the Double to an int by sticking (int) in front of it

```
Double Variable_Name_A = 12.0123990110001;
System.out.println((int)Variable_Name_A);
```

What is essentially happening is Variable_Name_A is being converted to an int, thus dropping everything after the decimal. You can also keep Variable_Name_A as a double with the following:

```
Double Variable_Name_A = 12.0123990110001;
Double Variable_Name_A = (int)12.0123990110001;
System.out.println(Variable_Name_A);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) There are a few ways to do this.  You can either use `DecimalFormat` (docs found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) or you can use a Cast (docs found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)).

Casting is telling your program you want it to view one data type as another.  In your case, you want a `double` to be seen as an `int`, which will drop anything beyond the decimal point.

```
double My_Variable_Name_A = -12.9345;

int casted = (int) My_Variable_Name_A;
```

`DecimalFormat` is a tool to specify exactly what you want to see in your output, though it outputs a `String`.  It can format a large variety of things, and it's best to check out the documentation on it.  It can get pretty in depth with the characters you might want to use.

```
    DecimalFormat dfMy_Variable_Name_A = new DecimalFormat("#");
    String newVariable = dfMy_Variable_Name_A.format(My_Variable_Name_A)
```

`DecimalFormat("#")` this is the part that decides the format.  If you wanted "X number of places after the decimal", you would use `DecimalFormat("#.###")` for 3 places.  If you wanted to make sure you had a comma to separate large numbers, you could use `DecimalFormat("#,###")` etc.

2)  As far as the second half of your question, you can import Math and use the abs() method in Java to remove negative signs. `Math.abs(My_Variable_Name_A);`